# Eclipse confusing package to be a folder

Tags: eclipse, package, directory

I have read some questions on this around here but my tries at the answer have not yielded success. Here is the problem:

- Package:com.me.a

  - Folder(under above package):b

    - Java class(under above folder):Myclass.java

The proper package structure is com.me.a.b, but eclipse thinks 'b' is a folder. When I right click on b and go to build-source, there is an option that says "use as source folder" which then does something totally unwanted - creates a separate folder with the entire package path as a source folder, and uses a default package:

- Folder: com.me.a.b

  - Package: default package

    - MyClass.java

How do I solve this annoying issue?

PS: I am unable to use images which to give a better idea but being new here, there is a restriction.

Comment: In the source code for Myclass.java is the package com.me.a.b?

Comment: Is the folder that contains "com" already set as a source folder?

Comment: Danny - yes, Myclass.java has the package declaration as com.me.a.b

Comment: BenjaminLinus - The folder containing "com" is already a source folder in the build path. It is actually a maven structure - this is the parent folder - src/main/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very strange. packages are basically folders, so saying that you have package com.me.a with a folder in it named b is essentially the same as having package com.me.a.b.
Or there is something wrong with the Eclipse's workspace metadata for this particular project?
Try creating new project with such package and class in it see if it is any different?

The behavior you describe when choosing "b" as a source folder is expected: you are basically telling eclipse that this folder b is a source folder, a root folder for source java files. this is the default package, every sub-folder of this one is considered a different java package...

Comment: You are right, in choosing "b" as source folder, the files under it come in as default package.

Comment: Seems like Eclipse had messed up the metadata about this particular file, I am guessing it was mislead by svn. I tried deleting this particular file from my local workspace, refreshed eclipse, then did svn synch and got this file again. This time upon refreshing Eclipse it seemed to properly place this file under the right folder. Thanks your indication about metadata was right.

Answer (score 2):

You have `project/com/me/a/b` set as the source folder. Your build path looks something like this.
[image]

You need to set `project` as the source folder. Your build path will look something like this afterward.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But my project had the appropriate root folder as the source(src/main/java). The problem it seems was caused by eclipse messing up its metadata about that particular file, probably caused by svn.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem with ONE folder between about 100 folders.  The solution turned out to be righ click on the folder (in the package view), choose "Build Path", and then "Include" (Instead of 'use as a source foldre' as the OP did). After that the folder turned into a package.